# Complete data frame with missing date ranges for multiple parameters

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
Date_from <- c("2013-02-01","2013-05-10","2013-08-13","2013-02-01","2013-05-10","2013-08-13","2013-02-01","2013-05-10","2013-08-13")
Date_to <- c("2013-05-07","2013-08-12","2013-11-18","2013-05-07","2013-08-12","2013-11-18","2013-05-07","2013-08-12","2013-11-18")
y <- data.frame(Date_from,Date_to)
y$concentration <- c("1.5","2.5","1.5","3.5","1.5","2.5","1.5","3.5","3")
y$Parameter<-c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C")
y$Date_from <- as.Date(y$Date_from)
y$Date_to <- as.Date(y$Date_to)
y$concentration <- as.numeric(y$concentration)
```

I will need to check the data frame if for EACH Parameter the date range begins at the first day of the year (2013-01-01) and ends at the last day of the year (2013-12-31). If not I will need to add an extra row at the beginning and at the end for each of the parameters to complete the date range to a full year for each parameter. The result should look like this:

```
Date_from    Date_to concentration Parameter
2013-01-01 2013-01-31            NA        NA
2013-02-01 2013-05-07           1.5         A
2013-05-10 2013-08-12           2.5         A
2013-08-13 2013-11-18           1.5         A
2013-11-19 2013-12-31            NA        NA
2013-01-01 2013-01-31            NA        NA
2013-02-01 2013-05-07           3.5         B
2013-05-10 2013-08-12           1.5         B
2013-08-13 2013-11-18           2.5         B
2013-11-19 2013-12-31            NA        NA
2013-01-01 2013-01-31            NA        NA
2013-02-01 2013-05-07           1.5         C
2013-05-10 2013-08-12           3.5         C
2013-08-13 2013-11-18           3.0         C
2013-11-19 2013-12-31            NA        NA
```

Please note: The date ranges are only equal in this example for simplification.

UPDATE: This is my original data snippet and code:

```
sm<-read.csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/tft6inwcrjqujgt/Test_data.csv?dl=1",sep=";",header=TRUE)
cleaned_sm<-sm[,c(4,5,11,14)] ##Delete obsolete columns
colnames(cleaned_sm)<-c("Parameter","Concentration","Date_from","Date_to")
cleaned_sm$Date_from<-as.Date(cleaned_sm$Date_from, format ="%d.%m.%Y")     
cleaned_sm$Date_to<-as.Date(cleaned_sm$Date_to, format ="%d.%m.%Y") 
#detect comma decimal separator and replace with dot decimal separater as comma is not recognised as a number
cleaned_sm=lapply(cleaned_sm, function(x) gsub(",", ".", x))
cleaned_sm<-data.frame(cleaned_sm)
cleaned_sm$Concentration <- as.numeric(cleaned_sm$Concentration)
cleaned_sm$Date_from <- as.Date(cleaned_sm$Date_from)
cleaned_sm$Date_to <- as.Date(cleaned_sm$Date_to)
```

Added code based on @jasbner:

```
cleaned_sm %>%
   group_by(Parameter) %>%
   do(add_row(.,
                 Date_from = ymd(max(Date_to))+1 ,
                 Date_to = ymd(paste(year(max(Date_to)),"1231")),
                 Parameter = .$Parameter[1])) %>%
   do(add_row(.,
                 Date_to = ymd(min(Date_from))-1, 
                 Date_from = ymd(paste(year(min(Date_from)),"0101")) ,
                 Parameter = .$Parameter[1],
                 .before = 0)) %>% 
   filter(!duplicated(Date_from,fromLast = T),!duplicated(Date_to))
```

Comment: Do the gaps in the middle matter at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My attempt with `dplyr` and `lubridate`. Hacked together but I *think* it should work.  Note this does not look for any gaps in the middle of the date ranges.  Basically, for each group, you add a row before and after that particular group.  Then if there are any cases where the date range starts at the beginning of the year or ends at the end of the year the added rows are filtered out.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
cleaned_sm %>%
  group_by(Parameter) %>%
  do(add_row(.,
             Date_from = ymd(max(.$Date_to))+1 ,
             Date_to = ymd(paste(year(max(.$Date_to)),"1231")),
             Parameter = .$Parameter[1])) %>%
  do(add_row(.,
             Date_to = ymd(min(.$Date_from))-1, 
             Date_from = ymd(paste(year(min(.$Date_from)),"0101")) ,
             Parameter = .$Parameter[1],
             .before = 0)) %>% 
  filter(!duplicated(Date_from,fromLast = T),!duplicated(Date_to))  

# A tibble: 15 x 4
# Groups: Parameter [3]
#    Date_from  Date_to    concentration Parameter
#    <date>     <date>             <dbl> <chr>    
#  1 2013-01-01 2013-01-31         NA    A        
#  2 2013-02-01 2013-05-07          1.50 A        
#  3 2013-05-10 2013-08-12          2.50 A        
#  4 2013-08-13 2013-11-18          1.50 A        
#  5 2013-11-19 2013-12-31         NA    A        
#  6 2013-01-01 2013-01-31         NA    B        
#  7 2013-02-01 2013-05-07          3.50 B        
#  8 2013-05-10 2013-08-12          1.50 B        
#  9 2013-08-13 2013-11-18          2.50 B        
# 10 2013-11-19 2013-12-31         NA    B        
# 11 2013-01-01 2013-01-31         NA    C        
# 12 2013-02-01 2013-05-07          1.50 C        
# 13 2013-05-10 2013-08-12          3.50 C        
# 14 2013-08-13 2013-11-18          3.00 C        
# 15 2013-11-19 2013-12-31         NA    C
```

Comment: In my example your code works but in my original data frame (please see UPDATE in original post) the code produces an error: `Error in lapply(list(...), .num_to_date) : object 'Date_to' not found`. I have no idea why it produces this error as the structure of my original data frame is the same as the one in my example.

Comment: @Matt try it now

Comment: Works like a charm now.

Comment: Had to add `.$` in front of each parameter to properly reference.  Not really sure why it was/was not necessary between the datasets.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it requires a combination of different packages to attack it. I am using `tidyr`, `data.table`, and I used `lubridate`.

```
date.start <- seq.Date(as.Date("2013-01-01"), as.Date("2013-12-31"), by = "day")
Date.Int   <- data.frame(Date_from = date.start, Date_to = date.start)
y_wide     <- y %>% spread(Parameter, concentration)
y_wide     <- as.data.table(setkey(as.data.table(y_wide), Date_from, Date_to))
Date.Int    <- as.data.table(setkey(as.data.table(Date.Int), Date_from, Date_to))
dats <- foverlaps(Date.Int, y_wide, nomatch = NA)

fin.dat <- dats %>% 
mutate(A    = ifelse(is.na(A), -5, A), 
       seqs = cumsum(!is.na(A) & A != lag(A, default = -5))) %>% 
group_by(seqs) %>% 
summarise(Date_from = first(i.Date_from),                                                                                                    
          Date_to   = last(i.Date_to)   ,                                                                                                        
          A = first(A),                                                                                                        
          B = first(B),                                                                                                        
          C = first(C)) %>% 
          mutate(A = ifelse(A == -5, NA, A)) %>% 
          ungroup()%>% 
gather(Concentration, Parameter, A:C) %>% 
mutate(Concentration = ifelse(is.na(Parameter), NA, Concentration))
```

Okay, so I created a vector of dates from a start point to an end point (`date.start`); then I turned into a `data.frame` with the same interval names and interval dates for `Date.Int`. This is because `foverlaps` needs to compare two intervals (same date start and end dates in `Date.Int` are now officially intervals). I then took your data you provided and `spread`, turning it from long format data to wide format data and turned that into a `data.table`. `key`ing a `data.table` sets up how it should be arranged, and when using `foverlaps` you have to key the start dates and end dates (in that order). `foverlaps` determines if an interval falls within another interval of dates. If you print out `dats`, you will see a bunch of lines with *NA* for everything because they did not fall within an interval. So now we have to group these in some manner. I picked grouping by values of "A" in `dats`. The grouping variable is called `seqs`. But then I summarised the data, and then switched it back from wide format to long format and replaced the appropriate NA values.

Comment: The parameter names are just examples. In my original data frame there are more than 15 different parameter names. I think it would be a bit cumbersome to change the code for a long list of parameter names.